# how to make a video call using pjsip and android

Tags: android, video, sip

I am working now on my  "voice over ipI android application using  the pjsip library; I want that my application handles the video call.

Is there any document that will help me to do it?
I'll appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check the link https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Video_Users_Guide

Answer (score 1):

Calling intent is

There is no difference, because there are no video calls in Android at the time of this writing. Any video chat application will be using ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL in all likelihood,

In the ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL broadcast receiver:

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
Object callType = bundle.get("android.phone.extra.calltype");
```

If it is a video call,callType is an integer of 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Video_Users_Guide](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android) for playing with video in pjsip. The following step you need to follow archiving video call
Add OpenH246 lib and configure with trank please follow document step [enter link description here](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android)

```
$ ./configure-android --with-openh264=/Users/me/openh264/android --with-libyuv=/Users/me/libyuv-android/jni
```

Make sure openh264 and libyuv are detected by ./configure-android:

```
...
Using OpenH264 prefix... /Users/me/openh264/android
checking OpenH264 availability... ok
Using libyuv prefix... /Users/me/libyuv-android/jni
checking for I420Scale in -lyuv... yes
...
```

Follow these steps to build pjsua2 sample application:

1. Make sure SWIG is in the build environment PATH.
2. Run make from directory $PJDIR/pjsip-apps/src/swig (note that the Android NDK root
   should be in the PATH), e.g:
   $ cd /path/to/your/pjsip/dir
   $ cd pjsip-apps/src/swig
   $ make
   This step should produce:

native library libpjsua2.so in pjsip-apps/src/swig/java/android/app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi

note: if you are building for other target ABI, you'll need to manually move libpjsua2.so to the appropriate target ABI directory,
 e.g: jniLibs/armeabi-v7a, please check ​here for target ABI directory names.
pjsua2 Java interface (a lot of .java files) in pjsip-apps/src/swig/java/android/app/src/main/java/org/pjsip/pjsua2

Add should auto enable AutoShow incoming and auto transmission in account like

```
  my_cfg.accCfg.getVideoConfig().setAutoTransmitOutgoing(true);
  my_cfg.accCfg.getVideoConfig().setAutoShowIncoming(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

PJSIP 2.4 is supports Video use refer the following link.
https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android#BuildPreparation